# How to use launch condition option in installation package using C#

Tags: c#, installation-package

I want my application to check (before start installation) for **Nokia_PC_Suite_rel_7_0_8_2**
my steps are :

1) I added Registry Search and it's properties are

```
Property = PCSUITERUNTIMEEXISTS, RegKey = HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PCSuite\Product, Root= vsdrrHKLM, Value = Nokia Pc Suite
```

NOTE: I got the value of `Value` property from the registry editor were i double-clicked on PCSiute then I found Product when I clicked on it I found a dialogue with 2 texts:

1. Value name
2. Value data

2) I added new Launch condition called "PCSuite Runtime installed, if not prompt user"
and its properties are :

```
    condition = PCSUITERUNTIMEEXISTS //(it's a drop down list so I selected the condition I created in "Registry Search"), 
Messege = [ProductName] requires Nokia_PC_Suite_rel_7_0_8_2  runtime. 
Please run setup.exe to install the prerequisites for this application.
```

Now in setup.exe I added Nokia_PC_Suite_rel_7_0_8_2.exe as a pre-requisites so when the user double-clicked on setup.exe he will ask him to install Nokia_PC_Suite_rel_7_0_8_2 if he cancelled the whole installation will stop.

What really happens is that when I click on .msi file is always displays the message ("[ProductName] requires Nokia_PC_Suite_rel_7_0_8_2  runtime. Please run setup.exe to install the prerequisites for this application.") although there is PCSuite Version installed on my PC.

So what to do? I want him to continue the installation if he found PCSuite if not display the message so the user will go to setup.exe.
Also when I un-installed PCSuite and clicked onsetup.exe it started installing PCSuite and when he finished he displayed the previous message and quit from the installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick test revealed that you need to omit the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\ from the RegKey. So your search Registry Key would look like:

```
Property: PCSUITERUNTIMEEXISTS
RegKey: SOFTWARE\PCSuite\Product
Root: vsdrrHKLM
Value:  Nokia Pc Suite
```

Nokia Pc Suite needs to be a value (not a Key) that has data. I noticed in my testing just having a Value in the Registry Key that has no data the check will still fail.

If you are just trying to check for the existence of a **KEY** leave the value blank.